# Extract text between three single quotes

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have the following in a file

```
description: '''
        This rule forbids throwing string literals or interpolations. While
        JavaScript (and CoffeeScript by extension) allow any expression to
        be thrown, it is best to only throw <a
        href="https://developer.mozilla.org
        /en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error"> Error</a> objects,
        because they contain valuable debugging information like the stack
        trace. Because of JavaScript's dynamic nature, CoffeeLint cannot
        ensure you are always throwing instances of <tt>Error</tt>. It will
        only catch the simple but real case of throwing literal strings.
        <pre>
        <code># CoffeeLint will catch this:
        throw "i made a boo boo"

        # ... but not this:
        throw getSomeString()
        </code>
        </pre>
        This rule is enabled by default.
        '''
```

with several other things in this file.

I extract this part in my shell script via `sed -n "/'''/,/'''/p" $1` (where `$1` is the file).

This gives me a variable with the content as one liner

```
description: ''' This rule forbids throwing string literals or interpolations. While JavaScript (and CoffeeScript by extension) allow any expression to be thrown, it is best to only throw <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org /en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error"> Error</a> objects, because they contain valuable debugging information like the stack trace. Because of JavaScript's dynamic nature, CoffeeLint cannot ensure you are always throwing instances of <tt>Error</tt>. It will only catch the simple but real case of throwing literal strings. <pre> <code># CoffeeLint will catch this: throw "i made a boo boo" # ... but not this: throw getSomeString() </code> </pre> This rule is enabled by default. '''
```

How can I now extract the part between the `'''` ?

Or is there even a better way to retrieve it from the multiline file ?

I'm on Mac El Captain 10.11.2 and GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Comment: Put double quotes around the variable, it contains newlines then.

Comment: This is YAML, right? Any reason you aren't actually using a YAML parser?

Comment: @DisplayName, ...to be clear, you mean double quotes *when echoing*, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
perl -l -0777 -ne "print for /'''(.*?)'''/gs" file
```

would extract (and print followed by a newline) the part between each pair of '''.

Beware that `perl` slurps the whole file in memory before starting processing it so that solution may not be appropriate for very large files.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, if you have `gawk` or `mawk` to your disposal:

```
gawk -v "RS='''" 'FNR%2==0' file
```

This assumes that there are no other `'''`-s in the file.

Explanation: It sets the record separator to three single quotes, and prints if the record number is even.

Unfortunately, it won't work with all `awk` implementations, as multi-character Record Separators are not part of `POSIX awk`.

Comment: (my) Mac terminal does not know gawk per default.

Answer (score 4):

Not as nice as the awk answer but as you were originally using sed

```
/'''/{
   s/.*'''//
   :1
   N
   /'''/!b1
   s/'''.*//
   p
}
d
```

Or shorter as pointed out by glenn jackman in the comments (slightly changed)

```
/'''/,//{
//!p
}
d
```

Run as

```
sed -f script file
```

#### Output

```
    This rule forbids throwing string literals or interpolations. While
    JavaScript (and CoffeeScript by extension) allow any expression to
    be thrown, it is best to only throw <a
    href="https://developer.mozilla.org
    /en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error"> Error</a> objects,
    because they contain valuable debugging information like the stack
    trace. Because of JavaScript's dynamic nature, CoffeeLint cannot
    ensure you are always throwing instances of <tt>Error</tt>. It will
    only catch the simple but real case of throwing literal strings.
    <pre>
    <code># CoffeeLint will catch this:
    throw "i made a boo boo"

    # ... but not this:
    throw getSomeString()
    </code>
    </pre>
    This rule is enabled by default.
```

Comment: You can condense that sed to `sed -n "/'''/,//{//!p}"` -- probably have to do `set +H` first in bash to turn off history expansion.

Comment: @glennjackman That was the reason i have included it in a script, IMO it's always more readable and as is immune to shell functions such as globbing,expansion etc. Anyway i added it to my answer as it is more concise than my original script.